# Redis client won't set values upon message received

Tags: redis, node-redis

The initial set of the values happens on the server (\complex\server\index.js):

```
app.post('/values', async (req, res) => {
  const index = req.body.index;

  if (parseInt(index) > 40) {
    return res.status(422).send('Index too high');
  }

  redisClient.hset('values', index, 'Nothing yet!');
  redisPublisher.publish('insert', index);

  pgClient.query('INSERT INTO values(number) VALUES($1)', [index]);
  res.send({ working: true });
});
```

On value submit in component (\complex\client\src\Fib.js):

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await axios.post('/api/values', {
      index: this.state.index
    });

    this.setState({ index: '' });
  };
```

the worker sets the value for the Redis client:

```
sub.on('message', (channel, message) => {
  redisClient.hset('values', message, fib(parseInt(message)));
});
sub.subscribe('insert');
```

However when list all the values inside the Fib.js component for each submitted index the component receives 'Nothing yet!'.

Why would it not receive the calculated values?
The complete repo is on https://github.com/ElAnonimo/docker-complex

Answer (score 1):

`redisClient.hset('values', index, 'Nothing yet!');` is asynchronous -- it needs to connect to Redis, send a message, wait for a response, etc.
So what probably happens is a race-condition, `redisPublisher.publish('insert', index);` runs before `hset` is completes.

I haven't gone over the code, so you'd also want to make sure to avoid a similiar race-condition with `subscribe()` being called after `publish()`.

Try this:

```
app.post('/values', async (req, res) => {
  const index = req.body.index;

  if (parseInt(index) > 40) {
    return res.status(422).send('Index too high');
  }

  redisClient.hset('values', index, 'Nothing yet!', () => redisPublisher.publish('insert', index));

  pgClient.query('INSERT INTO values(number) VALUES($1)', [index]);
  res.send({ working: true });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Didn't resolve my issue. I tried adding `setTimeout(() => sub.subscribe('insert'), 3000);` to the worker code with no desired result either.

Comment: Hey @ElAnonimo, have you ever been able to find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your `docker-compose.yml` file.
You have to specify the environment variables for the worker container and specify the redis `host` and `port` (just like how you specified for the server container):

```
worker:
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
      - REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Comment: @Karpukhin Olexiy  try this solution